# Java REST API to create and update new pages with contents in Atlassian Confluence‎

Tags: java, confluence, confluence-rest-api

Do we have any JAVA REST APIs to create and update new pages with contents in  Atlassian Confluence‎. I would like to automate the page creation updation, could you please anyone help me to do this using Java. For Jira, we have a JiraRESTClient API, for confluene, do we have any rest client API?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question to indicate what exactly would you expect in an answer? It looks like the answer now could be a single link to an API (which exists - package com.atlassian.confluence.rest surely contains everything you need)

Answer (score 0):

They do exist, but not sure why this question was asked for something so easy to find on internet.

Please find the links below:

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Createanewpage

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Updateapage